# Is the word biased or two faced?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Let's say someone fails at a task and gets berated by another person. That person also fails at that same task but it's ok for them to fail. What is the word to describe this person?

Comment: ... A *manager*?

Comment: very funny sir.

Comment: The question and the comment together are funny enough for an upvote!

Answer (score 5):

"Two faced" is when someone is "insincere and deceitful". "Biased" is treating differently people or things differently. But when you treat other people differently from yourself, that's "hypocritical".